# CSS pywal function returning blank after import from .cache/wal/colors.css

Tags: python, html, css

What are the next steps to take to import pywal to run a local startpage using the pywal variables on my machine. I have tried the following suggested css variables from the .cache/wal/colors.css. The tutorial can be found on his github [here](https://github.com/dylanaraps/pywal/wiki/Customization#css-variables) and pasted in this thread.

```
    /* Import the CSS file.
   Change 'dylan' to your username. */
@import url('file:///home/dylan/.cache/wal/colors.css');

/* Use the variables */
#nav-bar {
  background-image: var(--wallpaper);
  color: var(--color7) !important;
}

h1 {
  background-color: var(--color3);
}
```

Here is the code I stole from reddit on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4crnmztx/) that I am trying  to port to pywal(original code works fine), I am familiar with css but not importing other functions. (There is no JavaScript used in her repo) https://notabug.org/nytly/home It obviously won't work on jsfiddle because of the path its calling, but it looks the same on there as it does when I run it locally on my machine.

I commented out the part in root because my font and --branch function work but defining a color as a variable did not. 
i.e

```
--red; var(--color3);
```

Comment: [link](https://github.com/oakbrad/startpage/blob/master/main.css) where it is working for another user in a different CSS file/site, only one I am able to find at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

@import could not use url syntax to pass a file locally

I used instead:

```
@import "/home/josh/.cache/wal/colors.css";
```